# Directx 11.1/2 handle scene/camera speed on different pc's

Tags: directx-11

In my DirectX application I ran into a problem, when running my application on my high end windows 10 machine the scene is running smoothly and the camera is moving normal, but when i run the application on my laptop windows 7 machine the camera is extremly slow.

So how can I handle that and what can be the reason to that?

Comment: what do you mean by "camera is extremly slow"? Did you measure performance on the same workload? What is the FPS score for both OS'es (this can be measured by FRAPS)

Answer (score 1):

You need to scale your camera updates based on elapsed time not on frame-rate so that you get a fixed velocity. The rendering will not be as smooth on the low-end system, but the camera should move the same distance in the same time.

See [Understanding Game Time Revisited](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/12/03/understanding-game-time-revisited/) and the `StepTimer` class for a robust way to handle timing of the 'main render loop'

Comment: To say it short, let's say you want a camera to move of a distance `D` in one second, you have everyframe to compute `D'` for the current frame with `D' = D / fps`  or `D' = D * frameDuration`